# Построение двух графиков в одном с разным количеством точек оси X

Tags: javascript, chart.js, графики

Нужно совместить два графика в одном. Вся соль в том, что эти графики разные. Первый несёт в себе данные за 12 часов - точка в час, а второй данные за каждые 5 минут точка за 12 часов.
Другими словами у первого графика 12 точек, а у второго 144 точки(12 часов по 12 пятиминуток в час.

Можно ли как то это совместить ? Один график часовой должен быть столбчатый, а другой линейный.
Использую библиотеку Chart js

Знаю, что графикам нужно одно общее основание.